# Matrix which has every vector in the space as an eigenvector is square, diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve this linear algebra problem for some time and have gotten stuck.  I've been asked to either prove or disprove the following statement: For $V$ an $\mathbb{ R } $ vector space, if $A$ is a matrix with the property that $Ax \in \langle x \rangle = \{ax \mid a \in \mathbb{ R } \} $ for every vector $x \in V$, then $A$ is square and diagonal.  I suspect the statement to be true due to lack of counterexamples.  I can pretty easily show that $A$ must be square, otherwise the dimensionality doesn't work out right.  I haven't really got much of an idea where to go on the diagonal part though.  My great apologies if this is a duplicate question-I searched somewhat thoroughly and didn't find it anywhere, however.  Thanks in advance!
From the linear transformation view point, for every $x \in V$ there is an $a \in \mathbb{ R } $ such that $T(x) = ax$.  We have the expression
$$x = c_1 e_1 + \ldots +c_n e_n$$ 
where $e_i$ is the ith standard basis vector for $V$.  Therefore,
$$
ax = T (c_1 e_1 + \ldots +c_n e_n) 
$$
whereby
$$
a\left( \sum_{i=1} ^n c_i e_i \right) = \sum_{i=1} ^n c_i T (e_i) 
$$
Therefore, 
$$  \begin{pmatrix}
    a c_1 \\
    \vdots\\
    0
  \end{pmatrix} + \ldots + 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\ 
  \vdots \\ 
  a c_n
  \end{pmatrix} = c_1 \begin{pmatrix} a_{1,1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{1,n} \end{pmatrix} + \ldots + c_n \begin{pmatrix} a_{n,1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,n} \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  where the matrix representation of $T$ is the matrix $A = \left[ a_{i,j} \right]$, $1 \le i, j \le n$.  From here I'm having some difficulty once more.  Does this in fact give that $a_{i,j} = 0$ for $i \ne j$?  I'm having difficulty seeing how.

Comment: Hint: the result might be stronger, consider whether it is possible for $u+v$ to be an eigenvector if $u,v$ are eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Remember that the $i$-th column of your matrix corresponds to image of the $i$-th basis vector under the transformation represented by the matrix.

Comment: This viewpoint has gotten me in the right direction (I think).  I'm still having trouble with the very last few details-I reported my progress in an edit to the question.

Comment: @aherring, for the purposes of determining what the matrix "looks" like, it might be easier if you consider things one basis vector at a time. Applying your matrix to the vector $e_1=[1,0,0,...,0]^{T}$ gives you the first row, applying it to $e_2=[0,1,0,0,..,0]^{T}$ gives you the second row, etc. (Note that I take the transpose so that my vectors are columns, not rows).

Comment: @aherring, I have noticed a typo in my previous comment too late.. I meant, of course, that applying the matrix to $e_1$ gives the first *column*, applying the matrix to $e_2$ gives the second *column*, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much-your comments were a great help!